# Why is my Minecraft multiplayer world really laggy?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Me and my friends have a world, that's kind of like a smp just not a server. We have been playing on it for three and a half months or so and it's always been really laggy. Before we started build our houses and farms, it was always bad but now the host has to leave the world and rejoin so it's a little better, sometimes the host has to leave Minecraft and start it up again.
This has to stop so I came here, it has gotten to the point where you can't place blocks and it kicks you out of the world.
If you have the answer please get back to me, and thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using lan mulitplayer?  Is this pc or a different platform?

Comment: this is bedrock edition

Comment: its my friends world and its on a pc

Answer (score 1):

That really sounds like the PC running the server is having a hard time keeping up.

Consider upgrading it or switch who hosts the server for somebody that has a better PC. Or, if someone has an old PC lying around, consider using that PC for hosting and only that. It should help performance (since its not running multiple things)

Comment: i will try that and see if that works. thanks for answering!

Comment: it might be that it's running out of ram space.  If so, you need to allocate more ram, and then run the /stop command so that the memory will be saved to a hardrive and cleared from the ram.

Comment: ok thank you for getting back

Comment: it kinda worked but not 100% How do i get my world 100% lag free?

Comment: If it did, basically your option is get a computer that is better.

Comment: ok.... but its not my world and he does not have a lot of money so that's probable not a option for him, thank you for you time tho

Comment: Yeah I know it sucks, and you are right now at the fun part of playing on PC. Can I handle the annoyances or do I save up and buy myself an upgrade? I'm not an expert, but there might be ressources that limit the world size and would help the host PC not have too big things to manage.

Comment: Like if someone just ran in one direction and created a ton of chunks, something I heard is even if nobody is overthere it is harder for the PC to run.